# Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0. - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I'm new to Android Studio and when I try to run my app I get this error:

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
```

I understand I should run gradle build with `--warning-mode all` see the deprecated features, and `--stacktrace` to pinpoint where it's coming from but I don't how to run it, and I don't even know where the  gradle build is.

So I'd appreciate if you could point me in the direction of the gradle, and how to run it, a screenshot would be clearer though..
If you need any information, I'm happy to provide it. Thank you, in advance..